# Mongodb: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query.query(

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, maven

I am using mongodb in springmvc. My pom.xml is as follows:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-mongodb -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Now I got a problem that when I run the code below, there will be an exception:

```
mongo.updateMulti(Query.query(Criteria.where("age").gt(3).lte(5)), Update.update("age",3),collectionName);
```

the mongo is

```
@Autowired
MongoTemplate mongo;
```

and the exception is

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query.query(Lorg/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/CriteriaDefinition;)Lorg/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Query;
```

Can anybody tell me what's wrong with it? Thanks in advance.

My entire pom.xml

```
<properties>  
    <springframework.version>4.0.6.RELEASE</springframework.version>  
    <hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>  
    <mysql.connector.version>5.1.31</mysql.connector.version>  

    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.encoding>UTF-8</maven.compiler.encoding>
```

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->  
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>  
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>  
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>  
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>  
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>  
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>  
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>  
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>  
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>  
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>  
    </dependency>  

    <!-- Hibernate -->  
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>  
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>  
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>  
    </dependency>  

    <!-- MySQL -->  
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>  
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>  
        <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>  
    </dependency>  

    <!-- Servlet+JSP+JSTL -->  
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>  
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>  
        <version>3.1.0</version>  
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>  
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>  
        <version>2.3.1</version>  
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>  
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>  
        <version>1.2</version>  
    </dependency>  

    <!-- fastjson -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
        <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.22</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- log related -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.logback-extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-ext-spring</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient-cache -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient-cache</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context-support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>

        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>  
                <groupId>*</groupId>  
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>  
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-mongodb -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

enter code here

Comment: Can you check your war to see if it has `1.8.0.RELEASE` spring mongo db release version jar ?

Comment: You probably have multiple version of `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query`  class on classpath. Quick way to verify this is in eclipse is open type(ctrl+shift+T) Query, you should see more than one version jars containing it. remove the unwanted dependency.

Comment: There is 1.8.0.RELEASE spring mongo db release version jar in war and there is only one version of org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query. Is there other error?

Comment: Could you share entire pom.xml? And which application server you are using?

Comment: The entire dependency part of pom.xml is given and I am using tomcat8

Comment: The pom looks good. Notice, earlier in question you mentioned `<version>1.8.0.RELEASE</version>` and in the pom.xml its  `<version>1.7.2.RELEASE</version>` for spring mongodb dependency. So which one it is?

Comment: Also, I am pretty sure this is related to version mismatch. For spring version can you use `4.1.7.RELEASE` with spring-data-mongodb version `1.8.0.RELEASE`. [mvnrepo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-mongodb-parent/1.8.0.RELEASE)

Comment: Hi, I changed spring version to 4.1.7.RELEASE and spring-data-mongodb version to 1.8.0.RELEASE, but the same problem occurs